# Safari- HTML form is getting submitted twice. How to prevent it?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web-applications, safari

I have the following code

```
function submitSelf() { 
  var adhocMainJspPane = getFrameObject('adHocMainJSPPane',openerObject);
  document.Form.action="something";
  document.getElementById("tabID").value = adhocMainJspPane.cubeTreeFrame.document.getElementById("arePropertiesChanged").value;
  document.selfCloseForm.target="advancedPropertiesJSPPane";
  var tmpSum = getTmpSum();     
  document.selfCloseForm.action += "&tmpChk="+tmpSum;
  document.selfCloseForm.method="post";
  document.selfCloseForm.submit();
}
```

There is no other submit in the script.
The Html is

```
<BODY onload="submitSelf();">
  <FORM name="selfCloseForm" id="selfCloseForm" action="" method="post">
    <INPUT type="hidden" id="tabID" name="tabID" value="">
    <INPUT type="hidden" id="fromPage" name="fromPage" value="">
    <INPUT type="hidden" id="elementNo" name="elementNo" value="">
    <INPUT type="hidden" id="elementName" name="elementName" value="">
    <INPUT type="hidden" id="cubeAction" name="cubeAction" value="">
    <INPUT type="hidden" id="arePropertiesChanged" name="arePropertiesChanged" value="">
  </FORM>
<BODY>
```

The above for is submitted twice on SAFARI browser. How can I prevent it from doing so.

Comment: why are you trying to submit the form via JavaScript and form tag too.... you should remove the action from one of them..

Comment: even after removing the action or method attribute from form tag . the form is being submitted twice